# PHP 8, AJAX mail form to function.php doesn't work

Tags: php, functions, ajax, email, wp-mail

I have code that send message to email, it works at PHP 7.2, but after we changed version to PHP 8 it didn't works. Maybe someone have ideas whats wrong?

Function.php

```
function true_add_ajaxform(){

$multiple_to_recipients = array(
    'tse@yandex.ru',
);

add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'set_html_content_type' );

$message = 'text: '.$_POST['page']."\n";

$message .= 'text: '.$_POST['name']."\n";

$message .= 'text: '.$_POST['phone']."\n";

wp_mail( $multiple_to_recipients, $_POST['nameForm'], $message);

remove_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'set_html_content_type' );

function set_html_content_type() {
    return 'text/html';
}

}
 
add_action('wp_ajax_ajaxform', 'true_add_ajaxform'); 
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxform', 'true_add_ajaxform');
```

JS

```
var formType = '';
var page = document.location.href;
if (thParent.find('#actHidd .textAr').length > 0) {
    formType = 'author=' + thParent.find('#author').val() + '&comment=' + thParent.find('#actHidd .textAr').val() + '&idComment=' + jQuery('#commentCount').val() + '&rating=' + jQuery(".starRating input[type='radio']:checked").val() + '&action=ajaxcomments';
} else {
    formType = 'name=' + thParent.find('.callName').val() + '&phone=' + thParent.find('.callPhone').val() + '&nameForm=' + thParent.find('.callTitle').text() + '&page=' + page + '&action=ajaxform';
}

jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
    data: formType,

    success: function(newComment) {
        jQuery('#submit').addClass('clack');
        // console.log('clack');
        console.log(newComment);
        //                    alert(newComment);


        if (jQuery(this).is('#ericSend')) {
            jQuery('#innerEric').css({
                "display": "none"
            });
            thParent.find('.final').css({
                "display": "block"
            });
        } else if (jQuery(this).is('#sendForm')) {
            jQuery('#actHidd').css({
                "display": "none"
            });
            thParent.find('.final').css({
                "display": "block"
            });
        }
        thParent.find('.hiddForm').css({
            "display": "none"
        });
        thParent.find('.final').css({
            "display": "block"
        });

    }
});
```

When we use debug see this

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: call_user_func_array(): Argument #1 ($function) must be a valid callback, function "set_html_content_type" not found or invalid function name in /public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:292
Stack trace:
#0 /public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(212): WP_Hook->apply_filters('text/plain', Array)
#1 /public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php(469): apply_filters('wp_mail_content...', 'text/plain')
#2 /public_html/wp-content/themes/honestRepair/functions.php(1234): wp_mail(Array, '\xD0\x9E\xD1\x81\xD1\x82\xD0\xB0\xD0\xB2\xD0\xB8\xD1\x82\xD1...', '\xD0\xA1\xD1\x82\xD1\x80\xD0\xB0\xD0\xBD\xD0\xB8\xD1\x86\xD0...')
#3 /public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(292): true_add_ajaxform('')
#4 /public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(316): WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array)
#5 /public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(484): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)
#6 /public_html/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php(187): do_action('wp_ajax_ajaxfor...')
#7 {main}
  thrown in /home/p/progress55/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 292
```

Comment: have you considered using the modern REST API instead of the old admin ajax API? A REST API endpoint has a pretty URL and will try to tell you in english what went wrong with the AJAX request rather than failing silently

Comment: thank you for answer, yes we are think about it, but it fallback if this way doesn't work

Comment: I would consider abandoning admin AJAX in favour of the REST API. I also notice that you have defined a function inside another function, and that this was obscured because the code is not indented correctly. This is very bad, and likely causing problems on PHP v8, don't do that

Comment: thank you for answer, but debug says another information, we added that it say

Comment: It cannot find the function because it is defined inside another function, you need to move it outside and stop nesting php functions

Comment: sorry, but i cant understand what you means, are you talk me about this function "wp_mail" or maybe this "set_html_content_type"?

Comment: I'm referring to defining a function, not using a function, aka `function foo() { }`, you can't nest them, e.g. `function foo(){ function this_is_very_bad() { } }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the cause of your problem:

```php
function true_add_ajaxform(){
    ...
    function set_html_content_type() {
        return 'text/html';
    }

}
```

**You shouldn't nest function definitions!** Move it out of the function like this:

```php
function true_add_ajaxform(){
    ...
}

function set_html_content_type() {
    return 'text/html';
}
```

Comment: it very interesting because when we add //wp_mail( $multiple_to_recipients, $_POST['nameForm'], $message); our code work without errors and if you was reading debug information you can see errors about wp_mail function

Comment: sorry, you are absolutely right, its works, thank you for your help

Comment: that's because when `wp_mail` is commented out the hook does not run so the problem isn't triggered

Comment: yes, sure, you really 100% right, thanks :)